# contact form (specifice slection) and email

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to make a contact form and my problem is :

- by the option select the contact type (peter or Michael) , if i want to contact for example peter and press the submit button it the form goes to his email example peter@gmail.com and so on.... how to solve the problem inside (select option && contact_procees code) please advise me

```js
//// contact.php /////

 <form class="contact-form" method="post"  name="contact"  id="f"> 
     
    <table width="85%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
       <td>Contact Person  :</td>
     **strong text**  <td><select id="agents">
      <option value="1">Peter</option>
      <option value="2">Michael</option>
    </select>
        </td>
     </tr>
     
     
     <tr>
       <td valign="top">Text :</td>
       <td><textarea style="background-color:#f5f5f5; color:#000" name="msg" type="text" class="contact-textarea"></textarea></td>
     </tr>
     
    </table>

<br />
<br />

<table width="60%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
  <td width="150px"></td>
    <td align="left">
    
    <input type="reset" class="submit" value="Reset" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Send"  onclick="sendForm(); return false;" id="btn" />
    
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
 </form>

/// JAVA SCRIPT CODE SEND FOR

<script type="text/javascript">

function sendForm() {

  document.getElementById('btn').value=".....";
    
  var oData = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("contact"));

  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.open("POST", "contact_proccess.php", true);
  oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
    if (oReq.status == 200) { 
 
  if(oReq.responseText=="1")
   alert("Thankyou, the message is sent .");
  else
   alert("There was error in proccessing your request.Please try again later");
    } else {
         alert("There was error in proccessing your request.Please try again later");
    }
 
 document.getElementById("f").reset();
 document.getElementById('btn').value="Send";
  };

  oReq.send(oData);

}
</script> 

//// contact_process.php

<?php
error_reporting(0);
echo "1";

function error(){
 exit("0"); 
}


if(!isset($_POST['name']) or !isset($_POST['work']) or !isset($_POST['subject']) or !isset($_POST['msg'])){
  error(); 
}



$name=$_POST['name'];
$work=$_POST['work'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$msg=$_POST['msg'];


if($name=="" or $work==""  or $subject=="" or $msg==""){
error(); 
}

$message=
<strong>Name</strong> : '.$_POST['name'].'<br>
<strong>Work</strong> : '.$_POST['work'].'<br>
<strong>contact</strong> : '.$_POST['subject'].'<br>
<strong>Text</strong> : '.$_POST['msg'].'<br>
</div>';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From:Mypage Website <webmaster@mypage.com>' . "\r\n";

$subject="Contact";
$to="peter@gamail.com"; /// what should i do for others

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put your email id in select value like

```
    <select id="agents" name="agents">
      <option value="peter@gmail.com">Peter</option>
      <option value="michael@gmail.com">Michael</option>
    </select>
```

Get it in php like

```
    $to = $$_POST['agents'];
```

and then send the email like you are sending

```
   mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

I hope answred the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would POST the form to a page called "sendmail.php" and there pick up the selected value (peter/micheal).
You can name them 1 and 2 if you like.

The thing about having it javascript or in the html code is that the mail is in plain sight.
There are robots crawling for mails and the mails printed in html are a likely victim.

Once the send has been done you could echo out thank you and it worked, or did not work.

But my advice is POST the values and send them in php, that way it's secure from crawlers